# Miller Theorem circuit rappresentation

Tags: circuit-analysis

From the Miller Theorem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8q5zh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I feel strange that \$i_a\$ and \$i_b\$ are opposite and enter at the different extremes of the Z impedance. Usually, I found that a current passes through resistance in only one way. This confuses me a little bit. So I need to found the total current by KCL to found the real verse of current or someone else?

Comment: Haven't you drawn those yourself?

Comment: Isn't that the Miller Theorem?

Comment: Yes, both currents are in opposite direction - provided there is no sign inversion between input and output (as indicated in your drawing). If the gain is negativ (180deg phase shift), both currents are in the same direction. In the latter case, the Miller effect reduces the input resistance remarkably.

Comment: You have drawn it - what source information did you use?

Comment: Can you provide me your correct version of this theorem?

Comment: If the device has an input threshold, the negative feedback current will occur later on a rising input and enter a linear mode during transition where the negative feedback has gain.  Non-linear circuits have this property.

Answer (score 2):

If the device has an input threshold, the negative feedback current will occur later on a rising input and enter a linear mode during transition where the negative feedback has gain.  Non-linear circuits have this property. The net current is summed for each effect so the **input voltage and impedance  differential reduces towards zero** . Depending on gain and impedance ratios of C and R. for output, feedback and input, amplifying the effects of feedback in this linear region.

The MillerTheorem is well defined here how to split the feedback.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_theorem

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated in my comment, the Miller effect reduces the input impedance - provided the feedback element (in your case: "Z") is connected to an output node that is in antiphase to the input node (not the case in your drawing). Sometimes this is a desired effect - and sometimes not.

**Explanation**: Without feedback (infinize Z) the input current is driven from the input voltage Va only. However, with feedback (and signal inversion due to a negative gain -A) the input current is much larger than before because it is driven from a larger voltage Va-Vb=Va(-AVa)=Va(1+A). Hence, the input impedance appears much lower.

**Application**: The effect as described above is the Miller effect - which is the working principle of the well-known inverting opamp-based integrator stage (Miller integrator). Thanks to this effect the effective input capacitance appears to be much larger than the value printed on the part (because the input current is prop. to the conductance wC).

**Comment**: The opposite effect (corresponding to your drawing) without sign inversion between input and output is exploited not so often - in this case, the effective input impedance is increased ("bootstrap effect).